# How old is Chade?

Tags: age, realm-of-the-elderlings

Chade has always been described as old, even in the first books. I just finished the Tawny Man Series ending with *Fool's Fate*, and other characters are either growing old and frail

> such as Burich and Patience, or Shrewd in the first books or dying of old age (Lacey).

I find this hard to believe as these characters were always depicted as much younger than Chade in my opinion. Of course, this can be explained through some reasons:

> - Shrewd was being drained by Galen's false coterie
>  - Burich only seemed old because of his leg and blindness
>  - Chade uses the Skill to renew his health

But how old is Chade at this moment? I tried searching on the wikia but I am reluctant to continue after finding a rather big spoiler...

Comment: Your last explanation could be the most relevant. Don't forget Kestrel...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that there is ever a specific age given in canon for any of the characters other than Fitz, who was around six when he first arrived at the castle. And around 35 at the start of Fool's Errand (book 4).

These ages are taken from the [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characters_in_the_Realm_of_the_Elderlings#Fitzchivalry_Farseer) page, and I'll try to find the actual quotes in the books tonight.

> Due to his illegitimate birth and his lack of memory before the opening of the book, Fitz never learns his exact age. However, his estimate is that he was brought to his uncle Verity when he was about six years old. In the fourth of the books, Fool's Errand, Fitz is approximately 35.

Fitz is King Shrewd's grandson, of his eldest son. This gives a minimum age of 34 for Shrewd when Fitz arrives at Buckkeep. That would be both Shrewd and Chivalry having children at 14. Given the fantasy setting and Fitz's birth outside of wedlock this probably isn't too far off.

Chade is Shrewd's elder half brother. So at a minimum he's 35 at the start of the series and 64 at the start of the Tawny man series.